# Flutter/Firebase - Authentication (Phone Authenticate) for predefined user in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to design my **Firebase database** such that only registered user i.e - I have some predefined set of users who will be using application and only they will be able to sign-in. But the problem is I will get **UID** only after user is authenticated using OTP in phone authentication and I want to set UID as unique id for each user, So how will admin create the user without **UID**. I need **UID** for further operations.

[image]

I have one solutions but not sure if this is good idea.
I will create one collection as **Registered Users** with the phone no as unique ID. and users data like name, email etc. And then when user sign in using phone no. I'll first check in this collection if there phone no is present or not. If it present then I'll allow him to sign-in else not. And with that I'll create another collection as **Users** and move all the users data from **Registered Users** collection to **Users** collection with the **UID** as unique ID.

[image]

Let me know if this is correct approach or is there any better approach available for this kind of scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vikas, what is the solution here? Do you have any update, please?

Comment: Hi @Pramod - I am using same solution that I have mentioned above.